# Order a list by id

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm making a web application using Jquery, c # and ASP.Net in this application I insert id and make the id like next way:
the first two digits are the current day, the second two digits are the current month, the third two digits are the current year and a final digit is a consecutive number.

so if I generate the first id of the current day the id will be like this:
DDMMYY+CONSECUTIVE NUMBER

I want to order all id from oldest to newest based on date of id and the consecutive number

how could I make this using linq?

Comment: What have you tried?  What _specifically_ is not working?

Comment: @Rufus L, not quite. The date is of the format DDMMYY which means you would be ordering by day, month, year, then number. Presumably the required order is actually year, month, day, number. The only way I can think of doing this is a custom comparer

Comment: @RossGurbutt Oh, right! I must have had a dyslexic moment. Thank you.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `id` column?

Comment: what is the datatype of the id property which holds the  "YYMMDD + CONSECUTIVE NUMBER" value?

Comment: try `var orderedIdList = idList.OrderBy(x => x.Substring(4,2)+x.Substring(2,2)+x.Substring(0,2)).ThenBy(x =>int.Parse(x.Substring(6)));`

Comment: Just don't store data that way if you need it for sorting. Whatever trouble you experience (you don't specify) could very easily be solved by storing a datetime and the sequence number and generate the ID redundantly or in a computed field.

Comment: the id is a string, I want to order because I'm going to show a list of items in a dataTable and the items have to be order to oldest to newest

Comment: Yes, and I'm saying that using the ID for all kinds of sorting is a design flaw. You should *also* store a date value that matches the DDMMYY part of the ID and a sequence number. Or, better IMO, only store the date + sequence and compute the ID in a computed field.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store equivalent versions of the ids as strongly typed objects, I would write a comparer like the following (you can tweak it for your exact requirements and add validation if needed).

```
    public class IdComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            int xYear = GetYear(x);
            int yYear = GetYear(y);
            if (xYear != yYear)
            {
                return xYear.CompareTo(yYear);
            }

            int xMonth = GetMonth(x);
            int yMonth = GetMonth(y);
            if (xMonth != yMonth)
            {
                return xMonth.CompareTo(yMonth);
            }

            int xDay = GetDay(x);
            int yDay = GetDay(y);
            if (xDay != yDay)
            {
                return xDay.CompareTo(yDay);
            }

            int xUniqueId = GetUniqueIdentifier(x);
            int yUniqueId = GetUniqueIdentifier(y);
            if (xUniqueId != yUniqueId)
            {
                return xUniqueId.CompareTo(yUniqueId);
            }

            return 0;
        }

        private static int GetYear(string id)
        {
            return Int32.Parse(id.Substring(4, 2));
        }

        private static int GetMonth(string id)
        {
            return Int32.Parse(id.Substring(2, 2));
        }

        private static int GetDay(string id)
        {
            return Int32.Parse(id.Substring(0, 2));
        }

        private static int GetUniqueIdentifier(string id)
        {
            return Int32.Parse(id.Substring(6));
        }
    }
```

And then you just need to call `idList.OrderBy(x => x, new IdComparer());`

This feels much cleaner and easier to read than trying to do everything in one linq statement unless you have a specific requirement for doing this?

This class could then be unit tested and any issues / bugs would be easier to resolve than as part of a long linq statement.

Answer (score 0):

So the rules for comparing these id's is:

- If the year of one id is greater than the other, then that id is considered greater.
- If the years are equal but the month of one id is greater than the other, then that id is considered greater.
- If the years and months are equal but the day of one id is greater than the other, then that id is considered greater.
- If the years, months, and days are equal but the incrementing portion of one id is greater than the other, then that id is considered greater.

So now we just need to break the `id` value into 4 parts, after which we can do a proper comparison:

- The year part, which is `Substring(4, 2)`
- The month part, which is `Substring(2, 2)`
- The day part, which is `Substring(0, 2)`
- The incrementing number part, which is `Substring(7)`

Here's one way this could be done, by creating a class that implement `IComparer<Item>` (where `Item` is your class). Note: This answer assumes that your `id` column is a `string` since you're creating it by concatenating different values together. If it's not a string, then the arguments should be `int` values and would need to be converted to strings inside the method first:

```
public class ItemComparer : IComparer<Item>
{
    public int Compare(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return Compare(x?.Id, y?.Id);
    }

    private int Compare(string first, string second)
    {
        // Rudimentary argument validation - this could be improved

        // Null check - consider null as less than non-null
        if (first == null) return second == null ? 0 : -1;
        if (second == null) return 1;

        // Number check - if fails, return string comparison
        if (!first.All(char.IsDigit) || !second.All(char.IsDigit))
            return first.CompareTo(second);

        // Length check - if fails, return int comparison
        if (first.Length < 7 || second.Length < 7)
            return int.Parse(first).CompareTo(int.Parse(second));

        // Compare years
        var result = int.Parse(first.Substring(4, 2))
            .CompareTo(int.Parse(second.Substring(4, 2)));
        if (result != 0) return result;

        // Compare months part
        result = int.Parse(first.Substring(2, 2))
            .CompareTo(int.Parse(second.Substring(2, 2)));
        if (result != 0) return result;

        // Compare days part
        result = int.Parse(first.Substring(0, 2))
            .CompareTo(int.Parse(second.Substring(0, 2)));
        if (result != 0) return result;

        // Compare incrementing number part
        return int.Parse(first.Substring(6)).CompareTo(int.Parse(second.Substring(6)));
    }
}
```

Now that we have this method in place, we can order a list of items by the `id`. For an example, let's start with a simple class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

We can populate a list of these items and use our comparer class to order them:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var items = new List<Item>
    {
        // Second-most oldest item on Oct. 14, 2018
        new Item {Id = "14101801", Value = "Second"},
        // Fifth-most oldest item on Nov. 14, 2019
        new Item {Id = "14111901", Value = "Fifth"},
        // First-most oldest item on Oct. 13, 2018
        new Item {Id = "13101801", Value = "First"},
        // Fourth-most oldest item on Nov. 14, 2018 (id 02)
        new Item {Id = "14111802", Value = "Fourth"},
        // Third-most oldest item on Nov. 14, 2018 (id 01)
        new Item {Id = "14111801", Value = "Third"},
    };

    // Order our items by Id:
    items = items.OrderBy(i => i, new ItemComparer()).ToList();

    // Output our results
    items.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score -2):

If you change your ID to be YYMMDD + the extra number, LINQ's `OrderBy(foo => foo.Id)` will work exactly as you need. YYMMDD is naturally ordered.

If you don't have the capability to change the format of the ID, you will need to implement a comparer and provide that to `OrderBy`